# Cannot set Content-Type / MIME-type in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, mime-types

I'm using the following filter, explicitly setting the content-type for the response to application/json:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

It does not work, however, and the content-type when requested in a browser is text/html. The other headers work fine.

Comment: What happens downstream to the `HttpServletResponse`?

Comment: Is something down the `filterChain` overriding the headers? What if you move the `setContentType` after the `doFilter`?

Comment: The response is dispatched by a Spring @RestController. Moving the setContentType to the bottom of the method didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old.
I've had this issue and my workaround is:

```
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fname);
```

See: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index3.html